# CosmosDB: Unable to perform transaction on documents using stored procedures

Tags: javascript, azure, transactions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a partitioned collection, and I am trying to perform read/upsert operation on two different documents using stored procedures. These two documents are not necessarily in the same partition. One of the document needs to be updated while updating any other document.

As per my understanding stored procedures can be executed in a single partition of the collection. I need to update both the documents in a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know!

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 3):

> If the collection the stored procedure is registered against is a
>   single-partition collection, then the transaction is scoped to all the
>   documents within the collection. If the collection is partitioned,
>   then stored procedures are executed in the transaction scope of a
>   single partition key. Each stored procedure execution must then
>   include a partition key value corresponding to the scope the
>   transaction must run under.

You could refer to the description above which mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#database-program-transactions).

It seems we can't update cross-partition documents in a single transaction.

Otherwise,you may need to re adjust your database `partitioning scheme` because the partitioning key can not be deleted and modified after you have defined it.